# Set network files/folders to offline via script (batch/powershell)

Tags: powershell, offline

I'm trying to automate the process of right clicking a folder or file and then clicking the "Always available offline" in windows 7+.

I've not been able to find any command or batch way to do that. So far, I found this powershell script that simulate a right click operation on a context menu item (Always available offline in my case).

```
$o = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$o.Namespace("Z:\").Self.verbs() | `
Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Always &available offline' } | `
ForEach-Object { $_.DoIt() }
```

It doesn't work.

If I try to pass a folder or UNC path instead of a drive (let's say `Z:\foldertomakeavailableoffline`), all I get is *"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."* as if the folder I specify doesn't exist.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be rather helpful if you would post your $o.Namespace("Z:\").Self.verbs() result like this:

Mine are:

```
Name                                     
----                                     
&Open                                    
Git &Add all files now                   
Git &Commit Tool                         
Git &History                             
Git &Gui                                 

Git Ba&sh                                
Scan for Viruses...                      
Hg &Workbench                            

Restore previous &versions               

Combine files in Acrobat...              
Select &Left Folder for Compare              

&Disconnect                              
&Copy                                    
Create &shortcut                         
Rena&me                                  
P&roperties
```

In my eyes the issue here is that you don't see it and that is why id does not work. (It is also atypical menu item as the value are true/false).

I would try to do it the following "[pinning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309186(v=vs.85).aspx)" way:

If you need to pin a folder/file for a user try this:

```
$path = “\\path_to\shared\folder”
$objWMI = [wmiclass]”\\.\root\cimv2:win32_offlinefilescache”
$objWMI.Pin($path, 0x00001221, $true)
```

Which uses these bits:
`0x00001221`

`OfflineFilesPinControlFlagFill (0x00000001)`

> Fills the item in addition to pinning it. This results in the item being fully cached as part of the pin operation. If this flag is not
>   set, the item is only pinned and must wait to be filled by some other
>   means of synchronization. Note that the Offline Files service
>   periodically fills files in the background. If immediate offline
>   availability is not necessary, it may be better (performance-wise) to
>   not set this flag and let the service fill the file in the background.

`OfflineFilesPinControlFlagForUser (0x00000020)`

> Pins the items for the calling user. This is the flag typically set for a caller of this function. It is important to note that
>   Offline Files does not support a true per-user notion of pinning. When
>   an item is pinned for a user, it is pinned for all users of that
>   machine. An item that is pinned with this flag can be unpinned by any
>   user who has access to that file. The ability to access that pinned
>   file depends on the user's access rights to that file computed while
>   online.

`OfflineFilesPinControlFlagLowPriority (0x00000200)`

> Reserved for future use. 
>   (I like to use this one for it is LowPriority not to clog the system)

`OfflineFilesPinControlFlagConsole (0x00001000)`

> This flag is ignored if the OfflineFilesPinControlFlagInteractive flag is not set. If the OfflineFilesPinControlFlagInteractive flag is
>   set, this flag indicates that any UI produced should be directed to
>   the console window associated with the process invoking the operation.